# Learning to use Jinja2 templates, missing URL values

Tags: python, html, jinja2

I'm learning how to use Jinja2 templates (see code below). When I add an item to my form, I expect that the url will change to something like this.

```
http://localhost:8080/?food=steak&food=eggs&food=cheese
```

However, what ends up happening is that the first `food` will have a value, but everything else will be blank. It looks something like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/?food=asd&food=&food=
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
<form>
    <h2>Add a Food</h2>
    <input type="text" name="food">
    {% if items %}
        {% for items in items %}
            <input type="hidden" name="food" value="{{item}}">
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

    <button>Add</button>

    {% if items %}
        <br>
        <br>

        <h2>Shopping List</h2>
        <ul>
            {% for item in items %}
                <li>{{ item }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endif %}
 </form>
```

Here is the function to render the HTML:

```
class MainPage(Handler):
    def get(self):
        items = self.request.get_all("food")
        self.render("shopping_list.html", items=items)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For **item** in items?

```
    {% for item in items %}
        <input type="hidden" name="food" value="{{item}}">
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Ahh, I can't believe I missed that. I've been staring at this for 20 minutes. Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain, but I think the issue is with your `<button>` tag.  Try something like `<button type='submit'>`.  I think your current button just doesn't do anything.

[w3 documentation here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp)

Comment: hmm...tried it but didn't change the issue with disappearing values